# Does copy() builtin function perform shallow copy?

Tags: go

Below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var src = []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    var dst []int = make([]int, 10)
    fmt.Println(&src[0]) //0xc00001c210

    dst = src // shallow copy
    fmt.Println(&dst[0]) //0xc00001c210

    copy(dst, src) // shallow copy
    fmt.Println(&dst[0]) //0xc00001c210
}
```

---

performs shallow copy using a simple assignment and `copy()` builtin function

What is the purpose of `copy()` builtin function? Because assignment operation is performing shallow copy..

Comment: It copies values, it does not know anything about "shallow" or "deep".

Comment: @zerkms `&dst[0]` gives same address value `0xc00001c210` for both cases(assignment & copy() builtin)

Comment: `copy` does not allocate new memory, it copies from source to destination. In your code `src` and `dst` point to the same slice (after assignment).

Comment: ["*The copy built-in function copies elements from a source slice into a destination slice*"](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the same memory address is due to replacing the `dst` slice with `src` - this makes `copy` a no-op. With the `dst` and `src` slices pointing to the same memory, any modification will affect both slices. Typically you want to `copy` to a different slice/memory so slices can be modified independently.

`copy` is effectively a shallow copy. It only copies the memory directly referenced by the source slice to the memory referenced by the destination slice. It will not follow pointers and clone the structs underneath (if there are any).

Another example that highlights this with pointers:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type data struct {
    num int
}

func main() {
    src := []*data{&data{}, &data{}}
    dst := make([]*data, 2)
    copy(dst, src)
    fmt.Printf("src: %p : %#v\n", &src[0], src)
    fmt.Printf("dst: %p : %#v\n", &dst[0], dst)
}

// Outputs:
// src: 0xc000014260 : []*main.data{(*main.data)(0xc00001c030), (*main.data)(0xc00001c038)}
// dst: 0xc000014270 : []*main.data{(*main.data)(0xc00001c030), (*main.data)(0xc00001c038)}
```

This shows:

- The src and dst slices are using different memory (different pointers)
- The structs copied are identical (same pointers, not cloned).